# getting incorrect pagination and wrong layout view

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I have wrote a code stuff using bootstrap and jquery to create pagination, The code is working fine but it is giving incorrect pagination. Also I tried to divide the each cell into two columns. One column with image and another with (Name, Place, Age and Gender as rows), but that is overlapping the cell div.

My code is as given below

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

**[JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ldxc7f9k/)**

```
<section id="portfolio">
    <section class="container">
        <div class="figCont">
            <section>
                <figure>
                    <div id="left_col"><img src=""/></div>
                    <div id="right_col">
                        <div class="row">Name: Lessy</div>
                        <div class="row">Place: Mumbai</div>
                        <div class="row">Age: 18</div>
                        <div class="row">Gender: male</div>
                    </div>
                </figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>aaaa</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>bbbb</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>cccc</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>dddd</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>ffff</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>gggg</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>2328</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>9343</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>9323</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>9445</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>4349</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>5595</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>2439</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>6459</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>2329</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>3431</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>4552</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>5453</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>6554</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>7455</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>6343</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>7343</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>8343</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>9565</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>2329</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>9343</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>2329</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>2329</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>3439</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>2329</figure>
            </section>
            <section>
                <figure>9454</figure>
            </section>
        </div>
        <nav class="paging"></nav>
    </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Please read again the bootstrap doc.... A div.row without any div.col-xx-xx inside is absolutely not bootstrap friendly...

Comment: @YenneInfo can you show me an example similar to the above code stuff